# How to store a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA coding and have created a userform in Excel using VBA.
My question is how do you preserve a variable that has data in it from this form after the form has been closed or hidden.

I would like to use this data in another userform in the same workbook/sheet.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Simply save it to a named cell in a sheet (which can be hidden if you don't want users to see it).

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new module. Then, declare a public variable like,

```
Dim MyPublicVariable1 as [VarType]
```

or by

```
Public MyPublicVariable2 as [VarType]
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I've used the option of saving the variable contents to an unused cell in my spreadsheet and then reloading it into the next userform and it works fine. My next question is how can I use a variable to select which column to add data to in the spreadsheet ?